# How to explain the recursion in this factorial program?

Tags: javascript, recursion

This is the code in js which returns the factorial of a number:
Why 'else met' is printed first in the output given below? n>0 so the "value is ..." should be printed. Could someone explain please?

```
function factorial(n) {
  if (n>0){
    console.log("value is "+n*factorial(n-1));
    return n * factorial(n-1); 
  }
  else{
    console.log("else met");
    return 1;
  }
}
console.log(factorial(5));
```

This is the output:

```
else met
value is 1
else met
value is 2
else met
value is 1
else met
value is 6
else met
value is 1
else met
value is 2
else met
value is 1
else met
value is 24
else met
value is 1
else met
value is 2
else met
value is 1
else met
value is 6
else met
value is 1
else met
value is 2
else met
value is 1
else met
value is 120
else met
value is 1
else met
value is 2
else met
value is 1
else met
value is 6
else met
value is 1
else met
value is 2
else met
value is 1
else met
value is 24
else met
value is 1
else met
value is 2
else met
value is 1
else met
value is 6
else met
value is 1
else met
value is 2
else met
value is 1
else met
120
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

Comment: Try following the code to see how it would be run. Hint: `"value is " ...` can't be printed until `n*factorial(n-1)` returns, and so on, until you reach the base case (the `else` branch).

Comment: To understand recursivity, you must first understand recursivity once

Comment: You can't print to the first log statement until the function parameter returns a value. You get double output because you called the function twice, once as a param and once as a return.

Comment: @kevinternet it's called `recursion`

Comment: ooops sorry I believed this word exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this, you should have a basic understanding of
   Recursion. Anyways, about this code Recursion uses stack,

factorial(5) becomes=factorial(4)*5, so here factorial(5) is inserted
   into stack and which in turn calls

factorial(4)=factorial(3)*4 , so factorial(4) is inserted into stack
   and which in turn calls

factorial(3)=factorial(2)*3  ,now factorial(3) is in stack which
   intun calls

facotrial(2)=factorial(1)*2 ,now factorial(2) is in stack which
   inturn calls
        factorial(1)=factorial(0)*1,now factorial(1) is in stack which inturn calls
        factorial(0),here as it is not >0 ,goes to else
       part and then prints the else met condition first and displays as "else met" and then control returns to factorial(1)

now factorial(1) becomes 1*1, is removed from stack and control
   returns to factorial(2)

again factorial(2) calls factorial(1) which then calls factorial(0)
   so for factorial(2) prints  factorial(2)=>factorial(1)*2,
   factorial(1)=>factorial(0)*1 factorial(0)=>    else met and return 1
   now control is factorial(1)  it displays value as 1 now control is
   with factorial(2) it displays value as 2

the same process continues with factorial(3),4 and 5

But recursion is the worst process to take on for the fibnocci
   because of the multiple calls it does each time, instead you can
   think of using those values. I meant factorial(2) calls factorial(1)
   and factorial(0) factorial(3) also calls these and recalculates the
   values instead it can use the existing values 
   Try seeing dynamic programming approach for this .
    Here is the following code snippet for factorial using dynamic approach which is much faster

```js
var fact=new Array(5);
fact[0]=1;
fact[1]=1;

function Factorial(n){
 for(var i=2;i<=n;i++)
 {
   fact[i]=i*fact[i-1];
 }
 return fact[n];
}
console.log(Factorial(5));
```

Hope this helps